# Getting an unexpected token "." error while using middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, syntax-error, middleware

I have created a function `createAuction` that needs to be wrapped in a middleware called `middy`. I have created a **commonMiddlware.js file** in my directory inside which I receive a handler (such as createAuction) and then the function gets wrapped in the middleware. But when I import this file in my createAuction.js file, I get the following error in my Logs.

```
2022-11-29T11:09:40.028Z    undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception  {
    "errorType": "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError",
    "errorMessage": "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'",
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'",
        "    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:98:13)",
        "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)",
        "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)",
        "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)",
        "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)",
        "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)",
        "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)",
        "    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)",
        "    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"
    ]
}
```

**commonMiddleware.js**

```
    const middy = require('@middy/core');
    const { httpErrorHandler } = require('@middy/http-error-handler')
    const { httpEventNormalizer } = require('@middy/http-event-normalizer')
    const { httpJsonBodyParser } = require('@middy/http-json-body-parser');
    
    
    module.exports = handler => middy(handler)
      .use([
        httpJsonBodyParser,
        httpEventNormalizer,
        httpErrorHandler
      ])
```

**createAuction.js**

```
 const uuid = require('uuid');
 const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
 const commonMiddleware = require('../lib/commonMiddleware')
```

The code works fine if I comment Line 3 above, but without it, I can't use the middleware. Can someone please help me with the issue?

Comment: Is it `commonMiddleWare` or `commonMiddleware`?

Comment: Hi sorry! My bad. It is commonMiddleware.js everywhere. I have corrected it in my description as well. It is not working :(

Comment: Do you have a linter you can unleash on your code as a quick sanity check? Does moving the `.use` to the line above help any, as in `middy(...).use(`

Comment: @tadman I did as you said. I moved the .use([...]) up by a line, but it gives me the same error. Unexpected token "."

Comment: The real question is which `.` it's upset about. That's the only one I noticed in your code other than `module.exports` which would be surprising if the cause of the issue. Any "gremlins" in your code? Those are invisible characters JavaScript can interpret as an end of statement.

Comment: Exactly, the error is totally out of sync. I just can;t understand how is it a syntax error because my VSCode is not showing any red flags on any line number :(

Comment: I guess there are no gremlins as such. Could the error be because of the middy middleware itself because when I remove it, the code works fine but I still can't understand the error